# Remove 'null' from LinkedListMultimap in Java

Tags: java, collections, hashmap, guava, multimap

I have the below code, and I want to remove the 'null' values when printing or saving in a file.

There are times I don't have to pass any values to a variable. So, in those cases, I need the keys printed, but without any 'null'. How can I do that?

I have to use `LinkedListMultimap` as I may have duplicate keys and want to keep the order of entry to the map.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Multimap<String, String> data = LinkedListMultimap.create();
    data.put("NAME", getName());
    data.put("AGE", getAge());
    data.put("DEPARTMENT", getDepartment());

    data.forEach((key, value) -> System.out.println("[" + key + "]" + " " + value));
}
```

Current output:

```
[NAME] Joe
[AGE] 25
[DEPARTMENT] null
```

Expected output:

```
[NAME] Joe
[AGE] 25
[DEPARTMENT]
```

Comment: `if (value != null)`

Answer (score 3):

You can use a [ternary operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:):

```
data.forEach((key, value) -> System.out.println("[" + key + "]" + " " + value != null ? value : "{ Put whatever default value you'd like here or leave empty }");
```

Comment: Thanks it worked. The value needs to be in brackets:-
 equityTrade.getEquityData().forEach((key, value) -> System.out.println("[" + key + "]" + " " + (value != null ? value : "")));

Comment: @Oasis001 Check out the code below mine from Alexander Ivanchenko. Utilizes functional programming and can be faster. I am a fan of it. But some people believe the method that I used is more readable. So up to you :)

Answer (score 2):

> I want to remove the `null` values when printing or saving in a file

Storing and retaining `null` in the collection doesn't make any sense (*`null` - represents the absence of data, it can't give any useful information*), it's an **antipattern**.

To remove `null` values from the map - perform a bulk removal on a collection of values using `removeIf()`.

As well as with standard map to obtain a collection of values, you can use [`values()`](https://guava.dev/releases/23.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html#values--) method. As specified in the documentation, it returns a *view* over the values of the map and not an independent collection. And all the changes done to it, will be reflected in the map.

> Changes to the returned collection will update the underlying
> multimap, and vice versa.

That's how it can be done.

```
Multimap<String, String> data = // initializing multimap

data.values().removeIf(Objects::isNull); // removing null values

data.forEach((k, v) -> System.out.println( ... )); // printin the Multimap
```

Answer (score 0):

To achieve the expected output and remove entries with `null` values from your `LinkedListMultimap`, you can filter out the `null` values while printing the entries. Here's how you can do it:

```java
import com.google.common.collect.LinkedListMultimap;
import com.google.common.collect.Multimap;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Multimap<String, String> data = LinkedListMultimap.create();
        data.put("NAME", getName());
        data.put("AGE", getAge());
        data.put("DEPARTMENT", getDepartment());

        data.entries().stream()
            .filter(entry -> entry.getValue() != null)
            .forEach(entry -> System.out.println("[" + entry.getKey() + "]" + " " + entry.getValue()));
    }

    // Your getName, getAge, and getDepartment methods here

}
```

In this code, we use the `entries()` method of the `Multimap` to get all the key-value pairs as a collection of `Map.Entry` objects. Then, we stream over these entries, filtering out those where the value is not `null`, and print the remaining entries.

This way, you'll get the expected output without any entries containing `null` values.

Answer (score -1):

Something is missing in the code above. Actually it should be like this:

```
map.values().removeIf(values -> values.stream().anyMatch(Objects::isNull));
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this answer is incorrect. The user wants to be able to have the entries that have null values, they just don't want the null values to be spit out. You have outright removed the entires. Lmk when you fix this and I will undo my downvote.

Comment: And now that I think about it, where did you get the method `stream()` on the variable `values`? `values` is a `String` at this point in time, so how can you call the `stream()` method on it? I think your answer is fundamentally wrong.